# wpf image clip ellipse 4:3

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml

I need a little guidance. I'm trying to create an image in the shape of an ellipse. To view an image using [CachedImage](https://github.com/floydpink/CachedImage)

My current code:

```
 <Grid Width="100" Height="100">
        <cachedImage:Image Width="100" Height="100" Stretch="UniformToFill" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  
                           ImageUrl="https://i.scdn.co/image/efe952d45a24a33360e98b4b42d313576e29cece" >
            <Image.Clip>
                <EllipseGeometry Center="50,50" RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50" />
            </Image.Clip>
        </cachedImage:Image>
    </Grid>
```

Poroblem occurs if the image is in 4:3 format

This is my

[image]

I need this

[image]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: From the CachedImage home page: "If we use the native WPF  Image  control for displaying images over the HTTP protocol (by setting the  Source  to an http url), the image will be downloaded from the server every time the control is loaded." This is not true. WPF caches images when they are loaded from URIs. No need to use this control at all. Use the standard WPF Image control instead.

Comment: You may want to read the most upvoted answer to the [original StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1878060/1136211) that lead to the control on GitHub. Today it's obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `Width` and the `Height` of an Image control and at the same time `Stretch=UniformToFill` will inevitably crop part of the image unless its aspect ratio exactly matches the ratio of `Width` and `Height`.

You may however set `Stretch=Uniform` and put the Image control in another, larger Grid which is horizontally centered in the outer Grid. You would have to apply the `Clip` to the outer Grid.

```
<Grid Width="100" Height="100">
    <Grid Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Image Stretch="Uniform"
               Source="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Koala.jpg"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid.Clip>
        <EllipseGeometry Center="50,50" RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50" />
    </Grid.Clip>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped