# Offline Image Cache in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, caching, bitmap

I have a WPF app, which *loads images from URL* when there's internet connection & *should load those images from cache* whenever there's no active internet connection.

My **problem** is - images are not being cached to show in subsequent app-launches without any active internet connection.

I have searched for hours & tried almost all possible combinations of `CreateOptions` & `CacheOption`, but with the same problematic result.

The XAML code is like this:

```
              <Image
                   Width="{Binding MY_TILE_W}" MaxWidth="380" 
                   Height="{Binding MY_TILE_H}" MaxHeight="240" 
                   Stretch="UniformToFill">

                    <Image.CacheMode>
                        <BitmapCache  EnableClearType="False"
                              RenderAtScale="1"
                              SnapsToDevicePixels="False" />
                    </Image.CacheMode>

                    <Image.Source>
                        <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding ImageUrl}" 
                             CreateOptions="IgnoreImageCache"
                             CacheOption="OnLoad"/>
                    </Image.Source>

                </Image>
```

There's no more `C#` code, except the `Binding` codes of course.

Is it possible to achieve what I am trying? If yes, please how?

**Edit:**
My question was not exactly duplicate of [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878060/how-do-i-cache-images-on-the-client-for-a-wpf-application), as indicated in @Wilson's comment - since downloading the image each time is different in my use-case, but [the accepted answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22274082/1745218) [mentioned CachedImage library](http://floydpink.github.io/CachedImage/) has partially solved the issue.

I replaced the `Image` block with [the library's](http://floydpink.github.io/CachedImage/) this ui-element:

```
<cachedImage:Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Width="{Binding MY_TILE_W}" MaxWidth="380" 
        Height="{Binding MY_TILE_H}" MaxHeight="240" 
        Stretch="UniformToFill"
        ImageUrl="{Binding ImageUrl}"/>
```

Then direct builds from VS 2017 worked fine with offline image-caching, but the generated setup file (using Inno-setup) was crashing with the following log:

```
Set property 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.ItemTemplate' threw an exception.
Stack Trace:    at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
   at MyApp.MyWindow.InitializeComponent() in E:\w_Development\DotNet\MyApp\MyWindow.xaml:line 1
   at MyApp.MyWindow..ctor(Window window) in E:\w_Development\DotNet\MyApp\MyWindow.xaml.cs:line 54
   at MyApp.MainWindow.<NavigateWithDelay>d__3.MoveNext() in E:\w_Development\DotNet\MyApp\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 35
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0(Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at MyApp.App.Main()
```

I have posted [an issue regarding this crash in library's issue-board](https://github.com/floydpink/CachedImage/issues/9).

Comment: @Clemens, can you give anymore details - like a snippet, algorithm or link to such implementation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I cache images on the client for a WPF application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878060/how-do-i-cache-images-on-the-client-for-a-wpf-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [CachedImage library](https://github.com/floydpink/CachedImage) has served the criteria, as was indicated in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22274082/1745218).

I replaced the `Image` block with the library's this ui-element:

```
<cachedImage:Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Width="{Binding MY_TILE_W}" MaxWidth="380" 
        Height="{Binding MY_TILE_H}" MaxHeight="240" 
        Stretch="UniformToFill"
        ImageUrl="{Binding ImageUrl}"/>
```

Then got the exception after generating the setup file using InnoSetup script because of not adding the `DLL reference` in my InnoSetup script. Now all things are working pretty fine.